# 2-cocycles/Bigalois-objects over nontrivial liftings

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras

It is easy to extend group-2-cocycles to smash-products with Nichols algebras over the group (just trivially). The same certainly doesn't work for nontrivial liftings.

As I would like to check a construction of mine also over the latter, I wonder how to proceed...a first step is surely to treat liftings as Doi twists (by Masuoka for small $U_q$'s, by other papers for other cases, see 
 [my respective **MA-Question**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93445/liftings-of-nichols-algebras-over-racks-via-doi-twist))

- I tried explicitely **conjugating** the trivial extended group-2-cocycle with the Doi twist, but the calculations seemed to lead to nowhere :-(
- Does it help to abstractly consider the **category equivalence** induced by the Doi twist? Intuitively I would expect the Galois objects to be already determined by this structure? But how do I get the right explicit expression?

Thanks in advance :-)